# How to put special characers in a list?

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a Spinner in a form, I want to populate it with a list, it's work but i got special characters : "é" so I get a bad display, how to do ?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("- Choisir -");
list.add("Rachat de cr&eacute;dits");
list.add("Ren&eacute;gocitaiton de cr&eacute;dits");
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer posted isn't necessary. You should be able to add the actual text in your list. "Rachat de crédits". But if that doesn't work, "Rachat de cr\u00E9dits" would also work. That encodes in unicode. You should really put this information into strings.xml though.

Comment: in case he have a bulk of data retrieving from a server this can't be a solution.

Comment: What do you mean? I run Apps that retrieve Strings with Umlauts from servers on a daily basis. Both first options I provide would work fine. The 3rd option, obviously, is for non-dynamic strings.

Comment: I mentioned the case of string.xml .if we were following the first case we have to find out the unicode of all the special characters.

Comment: Which isn't difficult. Also, you can send the special characters from the server encoded in UTF8 and retrieve it on the clients end with no issues at all.

Comment: @Knossos It works where can we find other caracters in this format: \u00E9 ?

Answer (score 0):

For displaying special characters in android we have to use corresponding unicode value.you have to convert  special characters into unicode.next way to get rid from this take a look at custom fonts which supports complex characters.

You can accomplish this by creating custom spinner item and set custom font to those items.You can put the fonts into assets.

DejaVuSans.ttf  is an example for such font's.

Take a look at this link
http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/   too

Search for other font's which do the job if this hvn't good enough.

Or if the special characters is not compulsory try to remove it from the list

```
String regEx = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]";
int count= 0;

for (String value : list)
{
    list.set(count++, value .replaceAll(regEx, ""));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply retrieve them from strings.xml? I tried the following;

```
<string name="special_chars">ééé</string>
```

When I try it on Java side on a TextView for instance;

```
tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.special_chars));
```

It works, and it should work with a Spinner too.